# BBedit Script - Replace text field?

Tags: applescript, textedit, bbedit

Here's a piece of an EDL that I'm editing -

```
012 A005C004_22031_RPNV
*FROM CLIP NAME: A005C004_22031_RPNV
M2   AX     048.0

013 A003C002_220228_RPNV
*FROM CLIP NAME: A003C002_220228_RPNV
M2   AX      048.0

014 A005C004_220301_RPNV
*FROM CLIP NAME: A005C004_220301_RPNV
M2   AX      048.0

015 A005C007_220301_RPNV
*FROM CLIP NAME: A005C007_220301_RPNV
M2   AX      048.0

016 A005C001_220301_RPNV
*FROM CLIP NAME: A005C001_220301_RPNV
M2   AX      048.0
```

Using Applescript + regex, how would I go about creating a script to replace the 'AX' field after the M2 instance for the entire edl in BB edit? The M2 is a recurring comment and I would need to replace every 'AX' with the text field that appears after 'from clip name.'

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show more than just one entry? IT would be helpful to see which fields are stable and which are variable.

Comment: @TedWrigley updated post with a few more events from the EDL.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this might not be the most elegant regex ever written, but the following code should show you how to use BBEdit's grep-replace feature. YOU can tweak the result as you see fit:

```
tell application "BBEdit"
    -- this assumes the text you're working on is the frontmost document
    -- in the frontmost window of BBEDit
    tell window 1
        tell document 1
            -- the double-backslashes (\\) are because regex backslashes
            -- need to be escaped inside AppleScript strings
            set searchString to "FROM CLIP NAME: ([A-Z0-9_]+)\\nM2   AX"
            set replaceString to "FROM CLIP NAME: \\1\\nM2 \\1"
            replace searchString using replaceString options {search mode:grep, starting at top:true}
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```